# Hold Multiple Result Set in ASP.Net MVC Model through Sql Stored Procedure Without Using DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is as Procedure having two Select statements like below:-

```
Create PROCEDURE sp_test
As
Begin  
   Select RegId,Name from tblRegistration
   Select UserId,UserName from tblUser

End
```

Now, I have two Models for respective tables

```
public class Registration
{
public Int64 RegId { get; set; }
public string Name  { get; set; }
}

public class User
    {
        public Int64 UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName   { get; set; }
    }
```

I Need to fill both the Models Using "Common Class" below with data and do not want to hit DB multiple time

```
public class Common
    {
        public List<Registration> registration { get; set; }
        public List<User> user { get; set; }
    }
```

Using Below Code to connect with Database

```
public T StoredProcedureMultipleResult(string spQuery, object[] parameters)
    {
        using (DbConfig dbContext = new DbConfig())
        {
            string param = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                param = param + "{" + i.ToString() + "},";
            }

            int index = param.LastIndexOf(',');

            string sql = "[" + spQuery + "] " + param.Substring(0, index);

            T t = (T)dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql, parameters).AsQueryable<T>();

        }
        var value = typeof(T);
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
```

Comment: Add the code where you are presently hitting DB.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Adnan use Dataset for the same. There are no option to hold multiple table without using dataset in ADO.net.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `SqlDataReader`, which will retrieve all the data from both your `SELECT` statements in one shot - no multiple hits on your DB. Then, use `NextResult()` as many times as necessary, to transfer the data into your Model objects.

As an example, once you've received data into your SqlDataReader (using the ExecuteReader() command), you can code as follows:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    #region Result #1
    // (you can use reader.Read() to iterate through all rows of the result)
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Populate data from the first result into your model object
    }
    #endregion

    #region Result #2
    reader.NextResult();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        // Populate data from the second result into your model object/s
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             // your statements come here
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader#retrieving-multiple-result-sets-using-nextresult) for more detailed documentation